# How to create Vaadin server for post requests

Tags: java, http, rest, url, vaadin

I develop server part on `vaadin` and client is my applet. I want to send data from applet so server via `httpUrlConnection`, but I don't know on which address I have to send request and how to create connection on server. May be someone helps me with that case.

Comment: Vaadin is a web ui framework. It's hard to understand how you develop only the server component as Vaadin and use an applet as ui.

Comment: right, bad explain. I create identification manager. User open browser and in it pushes a button. my applet starts and when finish its work want to send data back to browser. I searched that in vaadin it possible via http-connection. but in example i can't find creation of connection.